# Validation of Microsoft Unity dependencies at build time

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Is there a way to validate Unity dependencies at build time?

We are working on migrating from one interface to another for logging and are running into situations where we are missing updating dependent classes after a change.  Unfortunately this ends up not being discovered until run time.

Are there any strategies for checking this at build time?  Ideally it would be done on a developer machine with Build Solution, but I would be happy with having checks run on our continuous integration environment.

Comment: What kind of "updating dependent classes after change" you mean? Switching to the new interface and checking the old one is never used anymore? Just delete or remove the old interface, the code that still uses it will not compile.

Comment: The problem is we do not have the man power to simply just delete the old one.  This interface is used in +30 different projects and each one needs to be manually tested and they all do not use the same implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a several different applications that all share common projects. Application A and Application B both register dependencies from Project 1. At some point, a developer for Application A adds new interfaces to Project 1 and they register the new dependencies there. However, nobody remembers about Application B and then when you build/deploy Application B, you discover the problem. Is that right?

Assuming that's the case, then there's an easy way to fix that, which is make Project 1 responsible for registering its own dependencies. Create a class like this:

```
public static class UnityHelper
{
    public static void RegisterTypes<T>(IUnityContainer container)
        where T : LifetimeManager
    {
        container.RegisterType<ISomething, Something>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
    }
}
```

Then when you register the dependencies, you just call your new class. Do this in both Applications A and B.

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    UnityHelper.RegisterTypes<ContainerControlledLifetimeManager>(container);
}
```

Now A and B never have to worry about what's going in Project 1. Anytime new dependencies are created, you just add them to `UnityHelper` and your applications get them automatically.

If you need multiple registrations of the same interface, you can name them and then refer to the names in the constructors.

```
container.RegisterType<ISomething, Something1>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>(UnityConstants.SOMETHING1));
container.RegisterType<ISomething, Something2>(Activator.CreateInstance<T>(UnityConstants.SOMETHING2));

public MyClass([Dependency(UnityConstants.SOMETHING1) ISomething something1, 
    [Dependency(UnityConstants.SOMETHING2) ISomething something2)
{
}
```

Comment: The problem is this isn't just simply two applications.  We are talking about +30 applications which use +5 implementations of this interface.  I like the idea of the unity helper and but we will need to probably have multiple variations of it...  

If someone messes this up, we still do not know until run time though.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a limitation of Unity; you won't find out those problems until runtime, but you can minimize them by centralizing your dependency registrations. I'm not sure why you'd need multiple versions, though. Unity does lazy loading, so you can register all the dependencies in one go, and the application only instantiates the ones it needs. If you are using multiple implementations of the interface, you can name them and then use constants to prevent hard-coding magic strings (see update to answer).